# Use of 'drawPolygonGeometry()' on postCompose event with vectorContext

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to draw a Circle around every kind of geometry (could be every ol.geom type: point,polygon etc.) in an event called on 'postcompose'. The purpose of this is to create an animation when a certain feature is selected.

```
listenerKeys.push(map.on('postcompose',
    goog.bind(this.draw_, this, data)));

 this.draw_ = function(data, postComposeRender){
   var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
   var flashGeom = new ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(extent);
   var vectorContext = postComposeRender.vectorContext;

   ...//ANIMATION CODE TO GET THE RADIUS WITH THE ELAPSED TIME

   var imageStyle = this.getStyleSquare_(radius, opacity);
   vectorContext.setImageStyle(imageStyle);
   vectorContext.drawPolygonGeometry(flashGeom, null);
 }
```

The method

> drawPolygonGeometry( {ol.geom.Polygon} , {ol.feature} )

is not working. However, it works when I use the method

> drawPointGeometry({ol.geom.Point}, {ol.feature} )

Even if the type of flashGeom is 
ol.geom.Polygon that I just built from an extent. I don't want to use this method because extents from polygons could be received and it animates for every point of the polygon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after analyzing the way drawPolygonGeometry in OL3 works in the source code, I realized that I need to to apply the style with this method before :

```
vectorContext.setFillStrokeStyle(imageStyle.getFill(), 
  imageStyle.getStroke());
```

DrawPointGeometry and drawPolygonGeometry are not using the same style instance.